# Return unique row when using GROUP BY based on a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Alright, lets say there's 3 tables:
Calendar, Users and Requests.

Calendar.ID, Users.ID and requests.ID are all unique. (If that matters)

I'm trying to pull everything from the dbo.Calendar plus users.color and requests.Status

```
SELECT calendar.ID, calendar.date, calendar.type, calendar.userID, users.color, requests.status
FROM calendar LEFT OUTER JOIN
    requests ON calendar.ID = requests.calendarID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        users ON calendar.userID = users.userID
WHERE(calendar.date >= '2016-06-01') AND (calendar.date <= '2016-12-30')
group by calendar.id, calendar.date, calendar.type, calendar.userID, users.color, requests.status
```

The problem i'm facing is if there's a completed request I get a duplicate row but in this case it should only display "pending".

```
ID  date        type    userID  color       status
4   2016-06-16  RE      A       #cc99ff     pending
5   2016-06-17  RE      A       #cc99ff     accepted
5   2016-06-17  RE      A       #cc99ff     pending
6   2016-06-13  LM      B       #ffff99     NULL
7   2016-06-13  LM      B       #ffff99     accepted
```

I'm trying to get this:

```
ID  date        type    userID  color       status
4   2016-06-16  RE      A       #cc99ff     pending
5   2016-06-17  RE      A       #cc99ff     pending
6   2016-06-13  LM      B       #ffff99     NULL
7   2016-06-13  LM      B       #ffff99     accepted
```

FYI I haven't touched SQL in over 8 years, this is just a personal project i'm working on.

Comment: use whare status <> 'accepted'

Comment: Sorry, i still need other records that have the 'accepted' value.

Comment: as you are showing status column to,so its not possible to omit 'accepted'  while using group by,because logically the both 'pending' and 'accepted' are differ for same id date and etc columns.

Comment: Can you please clarify your criteria for selection of the records? you changed example afterwards, does that mean you want only one record based on status priority? Then Gordon answer will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want one row per `id` and user, but prioritized:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT c.ID, c.date, c.type, u.userID, u.color, r.status,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.ID, u.userID
                                ORDER BY (CASE WHEN r.status = 'Accepted' then 1  
                                               ELSE 2
                                          END) desc
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM calendar c LEFT OUTER JOIN
           requests r
           ON c.ID = r.calendarID LEFT OUTER JOIN
           users u
           ON c.userID = u.userID
      WHERE (c.date >= '2016-06-01') AND (c.date <= '2016-12-30')
    ) rcu
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: this worked only thing is rownum needed to be seqnum. well done sir you are a god.

Answer (score 0):

You don't are using aggregate functio then you don't need group  by 
If you want distinct rows eventually use disctinct in your select
for  the statu add a condition  `status != 'accepted'`

```
    SELECT calendar.ID, calendar.date, calendar.type, calendar.userID, users.color, requests.status
    FROM calendar LEFT OUTER JOIN
        requests ON calendar.ID = requests.calendarID LEFT OUTER JOIN
            users ON calendar.userID = users.userID
    WHERE(calendar.date >= '2016-06-01') AND (calendar.date <= '2016-12-30')
    AND requests.status != 'accepted' ;
```